# Issue when using dataFolder on Java plugin - cannot find where the folder is saved

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I would like to save the output (player coordinates) of the minecraft game into a file named player.log.

If my player username was 'abce', the name of the file should be 'abce.log'.

However, I can't find where on my server this file has been stored - it is not in the plugins folder where I would like it to be.

I have attached a screenshot below of where I would like the file to be saved (which is **remotely** in an **external shock-byte server plugins folder**).

I have the following code:

```
package newestfile.here.newestplugin;

import java.util.UUID;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.File;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerQuitEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitTask;
import java.nio.file.Files; 

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener
{
    boolean stopRepeater;
    HashMap<UUID, BukkitTask> tasks = new HashMap<>();
 
    private File dataFolder;
    
    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this,this);
        getLogger().info("HELLO! WELCOME TO THE TRACKER PLUGIN");
        dataFolder = new File(getDataFolder(), "data"); 
        dataFolder.mkdirs();
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void onLogin(final PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        final Player thePlayer = event.getPlayer();
        this.stopRepeater = true;
        final Location playerSpawnLocation = thePlayer.getLocation();
        getLogger().info("Welcome " + thePlayer.getName() + ". Your current position is: " + playerSpawnLocation);  
        BukkitTask task = getServer().getScheduler().runTaskTimer(this, () -> {
            if(this.stopRepeater) {
                this.logToFile(thePlayer, thePlayer.getLocation());
            }
        }, 0L, 20L);
        tasks.put(thePlayer.getUniqueId(),task);}
    
    @EventHandler
    public void onQuit(final PlayerQuitEvent event) {
        Player thePlayer = event.getPlayer(); 
        if(!thePlayer.isOnline()) {
            this.stopRepeater = false;  
            getLogger().info(String.valueOf(event.getPlayer().getName()) + " has left the game");
            BukkitTask task = tasks.remove(thePlayer.getUniqueId()); 
            if(task != null) { 
               task.cancel();
            }
        }
    }

    public void logToFile(final Player currentPlayer, final Location playerCurrentLocation) {
        try {
            String content = String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())) + " CurrentLocation(x,y,z): " + playerCurrentLocation.getBlockX() + " " + playerCurrentLocation.getBlockY() + " " + playerCurrentLocation.getBlockZ() + "\n";
            final File file = new File(dataFolder, currentPlayer.getName() + ".log");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            Files.write(file.toPath(),content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

[image]

Output of the **'latest.log'** file:

[image]

Comment: can you show console output ? Also, next time be sure to do a [mre] to don't have to explain the full feature you're trying to do but only the part which doesn't work

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Could you clarify what you mean by console output?

Comment: I have added the 'latest.log' file above if that helps? :)

Comment: Yes, console output is log. Yes, it will help if you search in console for error of something. It's the first thing you should do. Also, try to only include content of your plugin, and to copy paste, not show a picture of text

Comment: I can't see any errors sadly :( What do you reckon might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

In fact your plugin is executed by the server.jar so the file spawn at same directory than your spigot.jar

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sd9y.png)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! The '.jar' plugin file is in my 'plugins' folder - so the output file should be in here? :)

Comment: It's not in the plugins folder it's in plugins/../ the folder before plugins folder.

Comment: it's not appearing in there either sadly :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @Dralexgon - I have finally managed to get it working! :)

Answer (score 1):

My code finally when my **'plugin.yml'** and **'pom.xml'** files contain the following information.

I can now find a 'player.log' file nested within my plugins folder which prints out the player coordinates as follows:

```
09-12-2022 09:55:21 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 47 -50 41
09-12-2022 09:55:22 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 47 -50 41
09-12-2022 09:55:22 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 47 -50 41
09-12-2022 09:55:23 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 47 -50 41
09-12-2022 09:55:23 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 47 -50 41
09-12-2022 09:55:24 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 47 -50 41
09-12-2022 09:55:26 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 47 -50 43
09-12-2022 09:55:26 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 46 -50 46
09-12-2022 09:55:27 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 45 -49 45
09-12-2022 09:55:28 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 46 -50 42
09-12-2022 09:55:29 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 47 -50 37
09-12-2022 09:55:30 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 47 -49 33
09-12-2022 09:55:31 CurrentLocation(x,y,z): 46 -49 30
```

**plugin.yml:**

```
name: newestplugin
main: newestfile.here.newestplugin.Main 
version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
api-version: 1.19
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>newestfile.here</groupId>
  <artifactId>newestplugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
   <resources>
     <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>plugin.yml</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
     </resource>
   </resources>   
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.10.1</version>       
              <configuration>
                  <release>17</release>
              </configuration>   
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
   <repositories>
       <repository>
          <id>papermc-repo</id>
          <url>https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>io.papermc.paper</groupId>
          <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.19.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```